# VSCode - How to enable CSS class autocomplete in Laravel Blade files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've installed the extension called `HTML CSS Support` - https://github.com/ecmel/vscode-html-css

I configured the remote URL's I want to autocomplete classes from:

```
"css.styleSheets": [
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.0-beta3/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css",
],
```

This works perfectly in HTML files, but not Blade files, or even PHP files.

So I went ahead and tried adding them:

```
"css.enabledLanguages": [
    "html", "php", "blade",
],
```

This still does not autocomplete in blade OR PHP files. I tried a `.blade.php` file and a `.php` file, neither worked. I also tried adding an entry for `*.php` to my VSCode file associations, which also did nothing.

How do I get this CSS autocomplete working in my blade and PHP files?

Answer (score 4):

So I ended up trying this extension instead - https://github.com/Zignd/HTML-CSS-Class-Completion

Which actually works perfectly without even having to do any additional configuration.